# JavaScript & CSS scaffolding in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, scaffolding

I just wanted to ask if anyone knows why the scaffolding section isn't available in Laravel 8.x.
Recently I've tried the `php artisan ui react` but it didn't work.
And when I've tried it with the 7.x it worked fine.
Is Laravel dropping the support for that in 8.x or is it an upcoming feature or it has been changed to another method, thank you in advance.

Link to the documentation page [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/frontend)

Comment: This was moved to laravel Breeze, you can find it here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From laravel 6 to 7 upgrade notes: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

All authentication scaffolding has been moved to the `laravel/ui` repository. If you are using Laravel's authentication scaffolding, you should install the `^2.0` release of this package and the package should be installed in all environments. If you were previously including this package in the `require-dev` portion of your application's `composer.json` file, you should move it to the `require` section:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"
```

Did you run the command above before running `php artisan ui`?

Comment: Thank you! been reading the documentation for the 8.x for hours trying to find that. I believe it should be there but there's no mention for that.